# The Lie bracket of two horizontal vector fields is vertical?

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature, connections, principal-bundles

$P(M, G, \pi)$ is a principal bundle, $u\in P$, vectors $X, Y\in H_u P$ where $H_u P$ is the horizontal subspace at $u$.

A theorem that says $[X, Y] \in V_u P$ where $V_u P$ is the vertical subspace. [Reference: Nakahara p. 387, and p. 388 (10.34) for in tuition, where the book is proving the Cartan's structure equation].

The argument given in p. 388 suggests that the integral curves of the projections of two horizontal vectors $V=\pi_* X$ and $W=\pi_* Y$ must form a coordinate basis as $[V, W]=0$. How could this be true? We could have started with non-coordinate basis vectors in $T_p M$ and lifted them into $P$. Furthermore, why could $\pi_*$ and the commutator swap order in (10.34)?

Comment: I think you made a typo. One of those vectorfields $X,Y$ is supposed to be vertical (i.e. fudamental). Then your statement is correct.  
I only have a german version of this textbook and the numeration/pages seems to be different in the one I own.

Comment: @F.Conrad in the book (ver 2, English) it covers both cases: if both $X$, $Y$ are horizontal, the bracket is vertical. If one is horizontal while the other one is vertical, the result is horizontal. The argument on p. 388 is in section [10.3.3: geometrical meaning of the curvature and the Ambrose-Singer theorem].

Comment: As you state it, the question does not really make sense, since to form a Lie bracket, you need vector fields rather than just tangent vectors. Since you refer to Cartan structure equations this may be some vector fields that are mapped to constants by a coframe or something similar.

Comment: I think OP just means "horizontal vector fields"; i.e. the horizontal part of a vector field.

Comment: @AndreasCap Yes I updated the question title, $X$ and $Y$ are vector fields (at $u\in P$).

Comment: Even if you change the title, the question does not make sense in the current form. For example, if you take horizontal vector fields $X$ and $Y$ such that $[X,Y](u)\in V_u$, than take a smooth function $f$ such that $f(u)=1$ and $(X\cdot f)(u)=1$. Then $fY$ has the same value in $u$ as $Y$, but $[X,fY](u)=f(u)[X,Y](u)+(X\cdot f)(u)Y(u)=[X,Y](u)+Y(u)\notin V_u$.

Comment: @AndreasCap So the statement in the book is incorrect then, by this example. - or did you mean the question itself still doesn't make sense?

Comment: I don't have the book at hand, so either the statement in the book is incorrect or you did not reproduce it correctly. As I said in my first comment, the statement may involve horizontal vector fields that are mapped to constants by some local coframe or something like that. (A condition like that eliminates the freedom of multiplying by constants ...)

Answer (score 0):

Consider $\pi: P \to M$, your principal bundle projection, which is a submersion. Also, you have that
$$
D_u \pi: H_uP \to T_{x}M
$$
is a vector space isomorphism. As a result, you can conclude that $X \sim \epsilon V$ and $Y \sim \delta W$ are $\pi$-related (often called $f$ related in literature). This is a step out of OPs textbook, it is not obvious. This implies that $\pi$ can be "swapped" with the commutator, in this case restricted to horizontal vector fields, and gives us
$$
\pi_*([X,Y])=[\pi_*X,\pi_*Y]=[\epsilon V, \delta W]=\epsilon \delta [V,W] \to 0.
$$
We can do this since the leftmost term does not depend on $\epsilon$ or $\delta$. Hence the commutator has no horizontal part and is therefore entirely vertical.

Comment: a) But in the commutator the vector fields are taking derivatives of one another though. b) if we started with $V$ and $W$ that don't commute, then I lift them to horizontal $X$ and $Y$ in $P$, then...

Comment: c) if we had a horizontal $X$ and vertical $Y$, their commutator should have been horizontal. But $[\pi_* X, \pi_* Y]=[\pi_* X, 0]=0$?

Comment: You are right that they dont commute, the commutator $[V,W]$ does not need to vanish. But since we are able to take "small" vector fields such that $\pi_* X=\epsilon V$ (similar for $Y$), we can take the limit of $\epsilon \delta \to 0$, while $\pi_*([X,Y])$ and conclude that $[X,Y]$ must have been $0$, since $D_u \pi$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: You did not ask for the case for one field is vertical and the other once is horizontal. You asked both of those vector field to be part of the horizontal subbundle, thats why I didnt deal with that case. I think the one vertical/one horizontal case, iirc, can be dealt with by using again that the Lie bracket is preserved under nice mappings (in this case, a diffeomorphism given by a local flow).

Comment: I am a bit lost, in the last part did you take $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ to zero? Then $\pi_* X=\epsilon V \rightarrow 0$ as well hence $X$ is vertical? I think to keep $X$ finite you can't set $\epsilon$ to zero. In Nakahara book, the commutator is zero simply because he assumes/knows  $V$ and $W$ are coordinate basis - which I don't understand. (In the book, the zero part is not a limit, it is because coordinate basis commutes $[\partial_1, \partial_2]=0$.)

Comment: That is not the case, the commutator of 2 basis vectors does not vanish in general. In my german version he is mentioning an infinitesimal small parallelogram wich with 1 edge having length $\epsilon$ and the other edge having length $\delta$, hence the quantity $\epsilon \delta [V,W]$ becomes arbitrarly small, but that is NOT because $[V,W]$ vanishes.

Comment: Isn't the definition of coordinate (holonomic) basis that the basis vectors commute?

Comment: I cant find where he assumes the basis to be holonomic.

Comment: Also, I am 99% sure it is a limit. Why else would you take an infinitesimal parallelogram otherwise? You could just do with any pre-factor (i.e. of length 1). Futhermore, what does guarantee the existence of a holonomic basis on $T_xM$?

Comment: The necessary and sufficient condition of $\{e_a\}$ to be coordinate basis is that $[e_a, e_b]=0, \forall a, b$ - this was not clearly stated in Nakahara but can be found in other books.

Comment: Does he write coordinate basis in english? In german, he just writes "Koordinatensysten", which is just "local coordinates" and not "Koordinatenbasis" (which is coordinate basis, the thing in English)